# PHP/MySQL error - briefly losing connection to database

Tags: php, mysql

My web based application (used by multiple users [within our organisation] via web concurrently, by logging in) has suddenly developed this issue, intermittently the user while browsing it loses connection to database for fraction of second. When refreshed it comes back sometimes. It is getting pretty annoying now.

The error message is

> *Connection to the host is failed, perhaps the service is down.*

I saw mysql_error log file and found multiple rows of such messages:

> [Warning] IP address 'xx' could not be resolved: No such
>   host is known.
>
> [Warning] IP address 'xx' could not be resolved: This is
>   usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that
>   the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative
>   server.
>
> [Warning] Hostname 'unassigned.psychz.net' does not resolve to
>   'xx'.
>
> [Warning] IP address 'xx' could not be resolved: The
>   requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.

Are these two interlinked? Why these IPs (majority from China), only our ogranisation staff know of this web based tool.

Edit: It has returned after a brief hiatus. It shows a different message now

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.\r\n in C:\xampp\htdoc\xyz\config.inc on line 10

Line 10 in config.inc

> mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die('Could not connect to database: '.mysql_error());

What could be the reason now? How to fix it?

Comment: Are any of the IP addresses familiar to you? Do they relate to the MySQL server? If not then the messages in the log probably are not related to the database problem. The error message "Connection to the host is failed, perhaps the service is down.", is, as far as I know, not a standard PHP/MySQL message. Look in the sources if you can locate it, and see when it is reported.

Comment: You should probably block all IP addresses from China, and other countries nobody will ever (legitimately) access your webserver from.

Comment: Your mysql server is publicly accessible, it should be set to listen only on localhost, if its on a separate server, lock it down with iptables.. If you google `[Warning] Hostname 'unassigned.psychz.net' does not resolve to` it yields the same problem. `dos`ing, from china, most likely a bot.. just because only *some* people know the domain does not mean 15mins from booting up you not got some bot sniffing around.

Comment: This is probably not your problem, but as others recommend, lock your server down from bad behavior. No reason to waste resources on hostname lookups. Probably no reason to lookup hostnames regardless.

Comment: Thanks everyone for quickly responding. I will focus on the security part a little later, I want to fix the other issue on priority. 

Looks like that user authentication is failing intermittently. Any leads on how to fix it?

It is a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine with XAMPP.

Comment: Ah, Windows, have you tried to restart the server?

Comment: Yes, mutliple times. Anyhow I managed to track that error string to the config.inc file in xampp\htdocs\applicationfolder. I don't know why it did not get search when I tried previously.

Here is the line:"mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or DIE('Connection to host is failed, perhaps the service is down!');"
Strangely, nothing has been changed which should lead to this error. <me scratching head>

Comment: That's a normal connection, deprecated, but normal. Are there more users now than there used to be? You might be running out of connections. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html Also, the error message is not very useful. You can get a better message. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: Try this syntax: `mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die('Could not connect to database: '.mysql_error());` instead of `mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or DIE('Connection to host is failed, perhaps the service is down!');` to see if this gives you a clue.

Comment: I increased max_connection value, seems to be better now. Updated syntax. Keeping fingers crossed. Thanks!

Comment: The issue again seems to have made a comeback. I have updated my OP, could someone respond.